# How to create histogram with multiple arrays with various length, with percentage on y axes with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create histogram plot for multiple arrays, that will have shared percentage y-axis.

For example, this plot correctly:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# these are my measurements, unsorted
num_of_points = 10000
num_of_bins = 20
data = np.random.randn(num_of_points) # generate random numbers from a gaussian distribution
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=num_of_bins, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.3)
ax.set_title("Histogram")
ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Percentage")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=len(data)))
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 1]

But when I add another data with diffrent lenght, percentage for data2 is off, because PercentFormatter takes len(data).

```
num_of_points = 10000
num_of_points2 = 30000
num_of_bins = 20
data = np.random.randn(num_of_points) # generate random numbers from a gaussian distribution
data2 = np.random.randn(num_of_points2) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=num_of_bins, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.3)
ax.hist(data2, bins=num_of_bins, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.3)
ax.set_title("Histogram")
ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Percentage")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=len(data2)))
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 2]

So how can I have shared percentage y-ax, that will be correct for both data arrays?

Comment: You need to rescale the distributions so to give each distribution an equal (overall) area on the graph. One way is by producing a probability density. Check out the `density` argument in [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to solve this issue would be plotting the second data using the secondary y-axis.

Try this!

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# these are my measurements, unsorted
num_of_points = 10000
num_of_bins = 20
data = np.random.randn(num_of_points) # generate random numbers from a gaussian distribution
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=num_of_bins, color='blue', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.1)
ax.set_title("Histogram")
ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Percentage of data")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=len(data)))

ax1 = ax.twinx()
num_of_points2 = 30000
data2 = np.random.randn(num_of_points2) 
ax1.hist(data2, bins=num_of_bins, color='orange', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.1)
ax1.set_ylabel("Percentage of data2")
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=len(data2)))
plt.show()
```

[image]